# Piped or chained regular expressions?

Tags: regex, pipe, chained

Is there a way to write regular expressions where you do one match, and then do another match on the result of previous match, and so on ? Like pipes in command line.

As an example, let's say I want to find strings that begin with 'a' and end with 'z'. I can do this by first using "^a", and then use "z$" on the result of previous match. Is there a way to do this in one regular expression ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ^ or $ unless you're evaluating one word at a time with whitespace trimmed off the ends.

To find all words in text that begin with "a" and end with "z" (and contain only letters and hyphens), use something like this:

\ba[\w-]*z\b

Which for the sentence:

"The room was abuzz with people talking about how to use an adz."

...will match "abuzz" and "adz".